# Type theory: can multiple elimination rules be defined, in principle?

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory

I'd like to ask a question on type theory:

Consider the usual type theoretical definition of the natural numbers. We could give an elimination rule in the form:
[image]
or in the form:
[image]

I called the costants in the elimination rules $NatCata$ and $NatPara$ for the
parallel with catamorphisms and paramorphisms recursion schemas. I also omitted
the computation rules, as they are well known.

Now, this two ways to introduce the elimination rules let us build the same
functions (in the sense in which a function is his graph), but other details are
different (for example, the length of the derivation in the computation of a
function; the pseudo-predecessor function expressed with the $NatCata$ version
has to recur on all the structure, while with $NatPara$ is always a single
step).

What I want to know is this: is there any reason why we insist on having a
unique elimination rule?

Examples of such reasons may be theorems which are easier to state/proof, or
other meta-theoretic properties.

Could we have different elimination rules, if they are automatically determined
by the introduction rules (as in this case?). Would a logician consider this
approach tasteful?

Comment: The elimination rule for nat in dependent type theory has C being a type family over nat and both your elimination rules are special cases of that one.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais suppose for a moment that I'm not in the dependent setting. It's important for a type theory that the elimination rule is unique, or could we see various elimination rules as various ways to destruct a term, with different computational properties?

Comment: You may end up with two terms that are 'visibly identical' but not definitionally equal unless you add more rules to fix this. Why not define the first as a special case of the second? Derived rules are fine...

Comment: You make a great point here. I indeed the simple definitional equality. Thanks!